# What is VisualOffset?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am generating jpg from visual using following code (tell me the reference if you know):

```
var target = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)element.RenderSize.Width, (int)element.RenderSize.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
target.Render(element);
var jpg = new JpegBitmapEncoder() { QualityLevel = quality };
jpg.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(target));
```

It works fine for one visual, but for another it suddenly looks shifted with black background. Here is a *sketch* (I can't show real image):

[image]

After setting breakpoint at `target.Render(element)` I accidentally spot there is this property called [`VisualOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.visualoffset(v=vs.110).aspx):

[image]

Its value is exact as the offset of visual.

What is it? How do I change its value (it's `protected`)? How can I generate jpg from visual without having that problem? Could it be something to do with animations or data templates?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2009/07/03/rendertargetbitmap-tips/). The important parts here are `Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(target);` and `DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();`.

Comment: @Nitro.de, this sounds like an ugly, but a solution. If you post it as an answer I promise to up-vote it. Not sure about accepting it (reflection looks equally *bad* as creating another visual and painting into it with `VisualBrush`).

Comment: If you take a look at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) they're using the `DrawingVisual` too.

Comment: @Sinatr, also from the article "other people workaround this same issue by wrapping the visual they are going to RTB in a Border. This abstracts any transforms that were being applied by the original parent, and now RTB works well. ... It ‘imposes’ on Visual Trees.  Still, it works, so it is a choice."

Answer (score 3):

Currently I fix it with blunt reflection:

```
element.GetType().GetProperty("VisualOffset",
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(element, new Vector());
target.Render(element);
```

It works, but I doubt consequences.